# Order a collection as DESC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<%= render :partial => 'event', :collection => @events.sort_by(&:event_at)%>
```

This code shows a collection ordered as ASC, but i want to order this collection as DESC.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Even better, you can set a scope to sort your event and use it in your render.

In your Event model:

```
scope :desc, order("events.event_at DESC")
```

If you use Rails3, in your view you can simply do:

```
<%= render @events.desc %>
```

Comment: Then no problem, just adapt my example: `named_scope :desc, :order => ("events.event_at DESC")` and `<%= render :partial => 'event', :collection => @events.desc %>`

Comment: I got an error mess when trying this. In event.rb in models i wrote named_scope :desc, :order => ("events.event_at DESC") and then tried to call it with <%= render :partial => 'event', :collection => @events.desc %> but i got the error mess: undefined method `desc' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0xb5dac298>

Comment: You should hand the correctly sorted set to will-paginate. Or do something like `Event.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC'`

Comment: I do not quite understand your answer can you elaborate? What does 'the correctly sorted set to will-paginate' mean?

Comment: My mistake: it should have been: `<%= render :partial => 'event', :collection => Event.all.desc %>`. Whatever, if you're using will_paginate, do as nathanvda says (Depending on the version of will_paginate you're using, I think you can do  `@events = Event.desc.paginate :page => params[:page]` with the desc named_scope).

Comment: <%=  @events = Event.desc.paginate :page => params[:page]%> Loaded the events but i got all the events from all account when i only need under a certain account id like <%= render :partial => 'event', :collection => @events.sort_by(&:event_at).reverse %> made it work

Answer (score 113):

Like described on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

```
@events.order(event_at: :desc)
```

Comment: This is the best answer for Rails 3+ because it does the ordering in the database without needing to write raw SQL.

Comment: years later best answer still at the bottom

Answer (score 12):

In Rails 3 the correct syntax is:

```
<%= render :partial => 'event', :collection => @events.order(:event_at).reverse_order %>
```

Answer (score 8):

Depending of the kind of object you have, you will have different ways of doing the sort function.

If your object is an ActiveRecord, you can do it the following way:

```
@events.order('events.event_at DESC')
```

This will add an `ORDER` clause to your SQL query, sorting the entries before you retrieve them from the database.

The second solution is slower, as you're sorting your entries in ruby.
But if you're manipulating an array of objects, it's your only solution.

```
@events.sort {|a,b| b.event_at <=> a.event_at }
```

This will loop through all the events, checking each one of them for the biggest one with the `<=>` method.

You can also see [the sort documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003119) on Enumerables.

Comment: Sorry but im a newbie on ruby and rails. Whats does a, b stand for? Can you write an example with real names? Preferably with events_at

Comment: a and b are two elements of the array. You specify you want the second one before the first one.

Comment: Your example should be:  <%= render :partial => 'event', :collection => @events.sort{|a,b| b.event_at <=> a.event_at } %>

Comment: undefined method `desc' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0xb5dac298>

Comment: <%= render :partial => 'event', :collection => @events.sort{|a,b| b.event_at <=> a.event_at } %> This example worked also. Thanks..

Answer (score 8):

You can just reverse the sorted collection:

```
<%= render :partial => 'event', :collection => @events.sort_by(&:event_at).reverse %>
```

but as Yannis says you are better off sorting as you fetch things from the database ideally.

Comment: This made it work. But i want to try out the other examples for learning.

Comment: What is the difference between `.reverse` and `.reverse_order`? Are there any differences in speed or execution? I looked it up and found nothing.

Comment: `.reverse` is a method that you can use on any collection whereas `.reverse_order` is an ActiveRecord method to use at query time. Whilst this answer does answer the question I'd look at the accepted answer for a better way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to display a league table and order by points desc. After trying out several unsuccesful methods this is what worked for me in this instance.  I added this line to my controllers index method.

```
@teams = Team.all.order(points: :desc)
```

Comment: The Rails reference is here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `desc` method with parameter.

See below example

```
@events.desc(:event_at)
```

This will give you @events in descending order of `event_at` field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `views/sources/show.html.erb` the following `<%= render @source.docs.order(page_no: :asc) %>` works in Rails 6.

This calls `_doc.html.erb` which contains

```
<li>
  <%= doc.content %> (p. <%= doc.page_no %>) 
  <span class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs"><%= link_to 'Show', doc %></span>
  <span class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-xs"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_doc_path(doc) %></span>
</li>
```

Rails magic! An ordered list containing selected fields of `docs` that reference a `source`. And can click to edit or view the entire `doc`.

Thank you. One of the answers here pointed me in the sorting part.